# Loop through folder and put objects into one variable

Tags: php, class

I have a folder with files in them, in each file there is a class and the class name is the same name as the file.

I need to loop through each file and put the class into one object so I can use one variable to call any function/variable in any f the classes.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)? at least i think that's what you are asking

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very good approach (I even cannot imagine when it can be used), anyway - you can do it with php:

1. Use opendir to scan for files
2. Create global/static array where all classnames/corresponding file paths are saved
3. In your "proxy" class override `__call`, `__callStatic`, `__set`, `__get`, `__invoke`, where you will be able to create instance of another class (use require_once) or use already created and forward call to its method/variable
4. In all you classes change class names to new one

Also, check spl_autoload function, it is called when PHP don't know where to find Class source